# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 - unable to fix

Tags: pip

I' m having trouble with pip.

I have installed and updated Setuptools, pip, ez_setup and django. I have also tried to install the packages manually from a tar.gz with no luck.

Still getting the same error:

edit: I'm not sure how to post in the code

> Collecting postmaster   Using cached postmaster-0.9.3.tar.gz
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "",
>
> line 1, in 
>         File "C:\Users\m_cur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kkkd0jbr\postmaster\setup.py",
>
> line 4, in 
>           from postmaster.version import VERSION
>         File "C:\Users\m_cur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kkkd0jbr\postmaster\postmaster__init__.py",
>
> line 6, in 
>           from .http import *
>         File "C:\Users\m_cur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kkkd0jbr\postmaster\postmaster\http.py",
>
> line 146
>           except pycurl.error, error:
>                              ^
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\m_cur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kkkd0jbr\postmaster\

Comment: Consider pasting the code

Comment: I have tried other posts and updated setuptools.
I get this problem on my desktop as well as my laptop.

Comment: I have had this problem for several installations, im thinking it might be something to do with anaconda?
I have also tried uninstalling, deleting the path and all temp files, and reinstalling. Still no luck.
I have also had problems with MySQLclient and twill.